# I am encountering an error E0003 which says that the #include file includes itself

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, include, header-files, programmers-notepad

Everything was going perfect with the header file but the moment I updated visual studio it started giving me and error the moment I write

#include "std_lib_facilities.h"

The error pops up saying Severity   Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error (active)  E0003   #include file "C:\USERS\DHEERAJ\SOURCE\REPOS\PROJECT13\PROJECT13../../std_lib_facilities.h" includes itself    Project13   C:\Users\Dheeraj\source\repos\std_lib_facilities.h  5

I dont know why this is happening can somebody please help.

Comment: Have you looked in that header file to see if it really does include itself?

Comment: Look for maybe missing headers guards?

Comment: Don't put anything, especially #include, before the header guard.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions to all of you. @Some programmer dude . I looked inside the header file and it was all over the place was getting frustrated on this from a couple of days now thanks for helping me out.  You made my day. :)